# jQuery Mobile Windows Phone 8.1 hyperlink sms

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

with link

```
    <a href="sms:+39123456">Call Us</a>
```

in "Windows Phone 8.1 denim" asks to search the app in the store. It's possibile to hide the question?

In the official website jquery Mobile, Windows Phone 8 is compatible, but 8.1 is not mentioned.

Thank's

Comment: Are you opening this particular page inside in-app webBrowser control?

Comment: No. The page is open in a browser. The page is standard HTML5 for mobile with jquery mobile.